# pgfplotstable: adding 'mathsf' in 'preproc cell content' does not work

Tags: math-mode, fonts, pgfplotstable

I have cell processing which writes the value of the X column to the A column in superscript, that works as far:

```
preproc cell content/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable%
\xdef\X{\ensuremath{^{\pgfplotsretval}}}%
\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%% 
  ##1\X
}%%
```

If I add **`\mathsf`** here, that means `^\mathsf{\pgfplotsretval}` the method breaks down. 
What do I have to do for adding `\mathsf`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
A;    X
a;     x
b;     x
c;     x
d;     x
e;     x
}{\mytable}


\begin{document}

\section{Without mathsf -- works}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, font=\sffamily, 
columns/A/.style={%%
preproc cell content/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable%
\xdef\X{\ensuremath{^{\pgfplotsretval}}}%
\edef\temp{%
\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%% 
  ##1\X
}%%
}\temp},
},%%
]{\mytable}


\section{With mathsf -- works not}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, font=\sffamily, 
columns/A/.style={%%
%preproc cell content/.code={
%\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable%
%\xdef\X{\ensuremath{^\mathsf{\pgfplotsretval}}}% PROBLEM HERE!
%\edef\temp{%
%\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%% 
%  ##1\X
%}%%
%}\temp},
},%%
]{\mytable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: as has been said before if you use `\xdef` or `\edef` you will break most latex commands. You can not use `\ensuremath` here:  `\xdef\X{\ensuremath`

Answer (score 1):

As also mentioned by David Carlisle in the comments, you generally cannot use `\edef` and `\xdef` with LaTeX macros, as most commands are not e-TeX protected (in contrast to ConTeXt where almost everything is protected).  Instead LaTeX has the concept of “robust” commands, but `\edef` and `\xdef` have to explicitly be told to take care of them which is done using `\protected@edef` and `\protected@xdef`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep = semicolon, header=true]{
A;    X
a;     x
b;     x
c;     x
d;     x
e;     x
}{\mytable}


\begin{document}

\section{Without mathsf -- works}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, font=\sffamily, 
columns/A/.style={%%
preproc cell content/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable%
\protected@xdef\X{\ensuremath{^{\pgfplotsretval}}}%
\protected@edef\temp{%
\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%% 
  ##1\X
}%%
}\temp},
},%%
]{\mytable}
\makeatother

\section{With mathsf -- works not}
\makeatletter
\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type, font=\sffamily, 
columns/A/.style={%%
preproc cell content/.code={
\pgfplotstablegetelem{\pgfplotstablerow}{X}\of\mytable%
\protected@xdef\X{\ensuremath{^\mathsf{\pgfplotsretval}}}% PROBLEM HERE!
\protected@edef\temp{%
\noexpand\pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{%% 
  ##1\X
}%%
}\temp},
},%%
]{\mytable}
\makeatother

\end{document}
```